# pip3 и установленные через него пакеты работают только под root

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, права-доступа

pip3 и установленные через него пакеты работают только под root. Когда я делаю pip3 -V не под root, вылетает вот такое исключение, с пакетами установленными через pip3 под рутом таже история.Как исправить?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 8, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (unknown location)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

Comment: 1 - переустановить пакет python3-pip (или как он называется у вас в системе). 2 - устанавливать через pip3 без sudo (при необходимости указывать ключ --user: `pip3 install --user имя_пакета`), тогда пакеты будут работать без sudo.

Comment: @insolor, переустанавливал, не помогло

Comment: 1. никогда не используйте повышенные привилегии для задач, не связанных с администрированием системы. 2. наверняка вы использовали упомянутые привилегии неоднократно до этого, и в домашнем каталоге у вас образовался бардак — часть файлов/каталогов принадлежит не вам, а пользователю root: `$ find ~ -user root`. этот бардак надо исправить, и не повторять (см. пункт первый).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, как сделать так чтоб python3 и pip пренадлежали нужному пользователю тоже?

Comment: устанолвенные пакетным менеджером в систему? никак и ни в коем случае. // пользователю должно принадлежать всё в его домашнем каталоге. но ни в коем случае не то, что находится за его пределами (ну, за исключением, например, каталогов для совместно используемых временных файлов типа /tmp, /var/tmp и подобных исключений).